# canr run simple android "Web Apps in WebView"

Tags: android

This is my first android app and I'm a little disapponted because I'm not even able to run the google sample!!

Google sample: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Android version 2.1 (as suggested)

This is the log when I'm trying to run the app:

```
[2012-02-06 18:30:18 - XXX] ------------------------------
[2012-02-06 18:30:18 - XXX] Android Launch!
[2012-02-06 18:30:18 - XXX] adb is running normally.
[2012-02-06 18:30:18 - XXX] Performing YYY.Android.Android.XXXActivity activity launch
[2012-02-06 18:30:18 - XXX] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'test21'
[2012-02-06 18:30:18 - XXX] Uploading XXX.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-02-06 18:30:18 - XXX] Installing XXX.apk...
[2012-02-06 18:30:21 - XXX] Success!
[2012-02-06 18:30:21 - XXX] Starting activity YYY.Android.Android.XXXActivity on device emulator-5554
[2012-02-06 18:30:23 - XXX] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=YYY.Android/.Android.XXXActivity }
[2012-02-06 18:30:23 - XXX] ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=YYY.Android/.Android.XXXActivity } from null (pid=-1, uid=-1) requires android.permission.INTERNET
```

But I've already gave the internet permission!

these are my files:

**.java**

```
package XXX.Android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.*;;

public class XXXActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

    // Configuration of the WebView
    final WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    final WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();

    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");     

    }
}
```

**Main.xml**

```
&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;

&lt;WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/&gt;
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;
&lt;manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" package="XXX.Android"&gt;

    &lt;uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /&gt;

    &lt;uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" /&gt;

    &lt;application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET"&gt;
        &lt;activity
            android:name=".Android.XXXActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" &gt;
            &lt;intent-filter&gt;
                &lt;action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /&gt;
                &lt;category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /&gt;
            &lt;/intent-filter&gt;
        &lt;/activity&gt;
    &lt;/application&gt;

&lt;/manifest&gt;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" package="YYY.Android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            **android:name="XXXActivity"**
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />   
</manifest>
```

the problem was this: android:name="XXXActivity" and not android:name=".Android.XXXActivity"

Answer (score 1):

Move your permission outside of the `application` and `activity` tags.

```
...
</activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
</manifest>
```

Comment: Is it giving you the same exception?

Comment: yes, same exception, I put &lt;uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"&gt; almost everywhere but nothing changed

Comment: No, remove it from everywhere but where I showed you. Post your manifest if you need more help on where exactly it should be.